# X opens local firefox instead of distant one

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-x-session

I usually use vinagre or vncviewer to work from home, but since my screen size is not the same on both computers (Ubuntu on laptop, Fedora in the office) it's not comfortable at all.

I'm currently trying to use X, but when I use it to open firefox4 it opens the local version, which is not good for me (I want to have access to articles so I need the university's IP).

1. How can I fix this?
2. Better yet, is there a **good** remote desktop viewer that dosen't care about different screen sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the firefox problem, use the `-no-remote` option.

For a complete remote solution, I suggest [FreeNX](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX).