# Mathematica doesn't open over FreeNX

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, freenx

I followed the [great advice given to me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91939/x-opens-local-firefox-instead-of-distant-one) earlier, and installed a FreeNX server on my office computer (Fedora) and NoMachine's client on my laptop (Ubuntu 11.10). This indeed works great, accept for two problems:

1. All software works great, including MATLAB, but Mathematica refuses to open. It also refused to do so over X. Here's the error message: [image: mathematica error message]
2. I can't close the session. It doesn't bug too much because I can kill it from the console or through nomachine's session administrator, but neither the close button nor `Alt-F4` don't work. Maybe this means that I didn't configure everything as I should have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to install the package `mathematica-fonts` on your laptop, to resolve the first problem.

As to the second, I remember to have problems me too, but cannot remember just now the solution, probably the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>.

Comment: I'll try. But I have mathematica on my laptop so it's weird that this package is not already installed.

Comment: I just realised how silly that sounds. Eventually I'll have to give up my laptop license and use only my office's one. That's why I need to run it remotely although I have it locally.